# Can I suppress the Setup Assistant When Creating New Users on macOS?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, user-account, setup-assistant

I wanted to create a new user using Terminal and managed to do so by finding answers on StackExchange, but I was not able to figure out how to skip the setup assistant that comes up when you login to your newly created account.

I wanted to do this via command line as well if possible.

Does anyone know a way to skip setup assistant?

*EDIT - (Screenshots)*
There are 6 steps but i included two only. The rest are, turn on siri, setup touch id, choose theme (dark, light), true tone display.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The setup assistant aka “MacBuddy” runs when there is no user account. Are you hoping to skip the privacy warning, iCloud prompt or something else?  A screen shot might help us determine what prompt is not desired. Some can be suppressed easily, others not as easily.

Comment: I would like to completely disable "MacBuddy" if possible.

Comment: Those screens aren’t what I consider MacBuddy so you just need someone to list out all the parts of user onboarding you can and can’t suppress with MDM.

Comment: Here are two pieces of the puzzle to get you started... https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2016/01/28/suppressing-the-icloud-and-diagnostics-pop-up-windows-on-el-capitan-using-profiles/

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try using the two pieces and try to figure out the rest.

Answer (score 4):

This solved the problem that i was having:

Created a new user following all the normal steps. After creating the new user copied user's com.apple.SetupAssistant.plist (from ~/Library/Preferences/), and then just re-used that file for each newly created user. This allowed me to immediately login without the need to go through the assistant.

Thank you @bmike for your help!

Comment: i am having the same issue. Can you share the content of com.apple.SetupAssistant.plist file? After creating a new user using command line, can i just copy plist file to the /Users/<newuser>/Library/Preferences/ and will it skip the screens?

Comment: @yogeshkhandelwal According to the answer you can create the file yourself by setting up a new user and copying the file after logging in as that user for the first time.